# Spring MVC model attribute is not getting reset

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, modelattribute

quick question over here (hope so). Im developing a webapp, and trying to do a post submition using ajax. This works fine, the first time... On my second attempt during the same session, the model attribute sent to the server, is the first one. Somehow it is not getting reseted, even when I send a new instance of the model. Let me add some code:

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/productores/new.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newForm(){      
    log.info("Cargando form de productor...");  
    return new ModelAndView("/secure/Productor","productor",new Productor());       
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/productores/new.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processNewForm(
        @ModelAttribute("productor") Productor prod, 
        BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){

    log.info("Procesando nuevo productor.");    
    prodServ.guardar(prod);
    return null;

}
```

Productores.jsp (this page hold a grid showing all producers, and has a button to display a form to add one, as a modal dialog. This is using jquery ui dialog.)

```
    function showDialog() {
    var tag = $("<div id='modalForm'></div>");
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/SegurosWeb/productores/new.html",
        success : function(response) {
            if (typeof response == "object" && data.html) { //response is assumed to be JSON
                tag.html(response.html).dialog({
                    modal : options.modal
                }).dialog("open");
            } else { //response is assumed to be HTML
                tag.html(response).dialog({
                    modal : true,
                    position: ["center", "center"],
                    width : 1000
                }).dialog("open");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Productor.jsp (This is the form that will be poped up in a modal dialog)

```
            <form:form id="formProductor" method="POST" commandName="productor"
    class="formgeneral" onsubmit="doAjaxPost('/SegurosWeb/productores/new.html');return false;">
    <div id="row">
        <div id="separador">
            <p class="separador">Datos del Productor</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><form:label path="apellido">Apellido:</form:label> <form:input
                    path="apellido" type="text" class="formL" required="required" /></li>
            <li><form:label path="nombre">Nombre:</form:label> <form:input
                    path="nombre" type="text" class="formL" required="required"></form:input></li>
            <li><form:label path="matricula">Matrícula:</form:label> <form:input
                    path="matricula" type="number" class="formM" pattern="[0-9]{9}"
                    title="Ingrese la matricula del Productor (solo numeros)" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--fin de row-->
    <div id="botoneraform">
```

Ingresar</button> -->
            Ingresar
            Cancelar

and the ajax post in it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost(toUrl) {
    var a=$("#formProductor").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : toUrl,
        data: a,
        success : function(response) {
            $('#modalForm').dialog('close');
            $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

}

Do I need to specifically destroy the model attribute somewhere in the process to reset it? Or am I doing something really bad here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Model` attributes are only "alive" for the duration of one request. During processing they are added to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes and are then available for JSPs.

When you use `@ModelAttribute` in a handler method' parameter list like you do here

```
public ModelAndView processNewForm(
        @ModelAttribute("productor") Productor prod, 
        BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
```

Spring tries to create the Object from your request parameters. You have a number of these in your `Productor.jsp`, ie. the `<form:input>` elements. Every time you do a POST, it'll use those to create a `Productor` object.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. But I'm getting to think that my issue might be related to the fact that I dont do a standard form submition, but an ajax post, and that the dialog that has the form, might still be alive on subsequent calls, since I just do a "$('#modalForm').dialog('close');" to it.

Comment: @Emilio My point is the model attribute is not saved on the server side across requests. You must be re-sending the same every time.